# Can you configure the Thunderbird data root folder to be a different folder than %AppData%\Thunderbird\?

Tags: thunderbird

I am after changing the root of where Thunderbird finds all the user's data (profiles includes)
Currently it is specified on Windows as `%AppData%\Thunderbird\`

At its root there is **profiles.ini** which we can update to have each profile's  location point to potentially different locations.  (I perceive "Profile" in Thunderbird to mean a given email account data store and settings).

I am NOT interested in having to specify where each profile might be located, rather where all of them are located.

I looked under Thunderbird installation folder to see if there is some .INI file that would point to `%AppData%\Thunderbird\` but could not spot one.

Don't get me wrong, having the flexibility to configure each email account data store to different location is great, but also the ability to move all of them at once to a different volume is also an expected feature.  This will keep the relative paths (intact) as currently specified in the `%AppData%\Thunderbird\profiles.ini` .

Please let me know if this is something that can achieved.
If not please point me to where I file a request.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this post will help "Restoring to a different location" https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data#w_restoring-to-a-different-location Also There is   "Moving a profile" In the profiles.ini file, locate the entry for the profile you've just moved. Change the Path= line to the new location. _Same page_.

Comment: Thank you. The post is after relocating the roaming folder "Thunderbird", IOW, relocating the folder Thunderbird and all of its content  like profiles.ini, not just a profile.